# Understanding how drawLine works

Tags: java, methods, graphics, abstract

Given the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NewClass extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 90, 90);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.add(new NewClass());
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Why does it draw a line if the method `drawLine` is abstract and, as I managed to understand, an abstract method has no definition?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its ploymorphism. Some sub class that implements that method will be passed in.

Comment: shouldn't you call `super.paintComponent(g);` in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method? Just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paintComponent()` gets a non-abstract sub-class of `Graphics`, which implements `drawLine()`. It must get a non-abstract sub-class, since an abstract class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: And the actual implementation code will be platform specific, and due to the magic of OOPS and polymorphism, we can easily use it without having to know the internal structure of it. 1+

Answer (score 2):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Here Graphics have abstract method drawLine that does not have a body implemented but its subclasses have concrete implementations for drawLine. When paintComponent is called, object of appropriate non-abstract subclass of Graphics is passed