# Drawline() implementation

Tags: java

I've written a simple program to practice using some of the methods in the Graphics class, for instance the Drawline() method.  The program does what it's supposed to, it draws a line between two given points in the xy plane.  My question is WHERE is it implemented?  I USED the method but I'd like to see the implementation in the JRE library used to actually draw the line.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, the ONLY import my program uses is java.awt.*  This leads me to believe the implementation should be in the package somewhere.  I just can't find it.

Comment: The likely implementation is probably within the native level of the JRE, because it will be depend on the underlying rendering pipeline used by the JRE

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on stackoverflow recently :
[Understanding how drawLine works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235602/understanding-how-drawline-works)
It should give you some ideas about the way drawLine method works in Java

Answer (score 0):

Both Graphics and Graphics2D are abstract classes, therefore you need to find the concrete implementation by calling

```
g.getClass().getName()
```

Now you can search for the implementation in the concrete class (or in one of its superclasses). But it is quite likely that this is a native method, in which case you need to search further in the OpenJDK source code.